# PHP Foreach Loop to Print All Emojis

Tags: php, arrays, loops, unicode, emoji

I see that there's better support of Emojis in PHP 7 but no packaged set/library of emojis to reference from. As of now, I have to search and look for the UNICODE of the emoji I desire at https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode.

Would there be an easier method to obtain every single (latest) Emoji by iterating through a loop rather than referencing an array I would have to build on my own (copying & pasting every UNICODE)?

Comment: you could parse the page above with php or a user script. should be no problem and should be done in 10 minutes max.

Comment: are you wanting to retain the description for each emoji, or just know of all the available ones in general?

Comment: also are you wanting to keep them categorized? because they all fall within a hexadecimal range, so if you determine the range you can just increment between the start range and end range resulting in the list of emojis

Comment: I desire knowing all of the available ones so I can run a loop and print the whole set for various reasons. Categorization isn't really a requirement--as long as I can print all of them from some source without doing any tedious work (setting up an array of all UNICODE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents("https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode");

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($data);
libxml_clear_errors();
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' code ')]");
$unicodes = [];
$i = 1;
foreach ($nodes as $node) 
{
if($i % 2 === 0) {$i++;continue;}

    $unicode = trim($node->textContent);
    $unicodes[] = $unicode;
    file_put_contents("unicodes.txt", $unicode. "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

    $i++;
}

var_dump($unicodes);
```

It will take all the `Unicodes` from the site and store it in a file `unicodes.txt` and in array `$unicodes`. This simply uses `DOMDocument` to scrap the page. And Then you can get all of them using:

```
<?php

$emojis = file("unicodes.txt");

foreach($emojis as $emoji)
{
    $emoji = trim($emoji);
    $emoji = hexdec($emoji);
    echo "&#$emoji;";
}
```

Comment: Very interesting solution! I like how it fetches from that site into a .txt (however a few Unicodes are not separate on new lines -- I had to manually fix that). This appears to work out so far; however, I'm curious whether or not there are missing emojis in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of listing all unicodes by hand, you can define the ranges and use a loop to iterate over them and print them.

This could look like this:

```
$emojiUnicodeRange = [
[0x1f600, 0x1f64e],
[0x1f910, 0x1f91e],
[0x1f920, 0x1f927],
[0x1f300, 0x1f5ff],
[0x1f680, 0x1f6c1],
[0x1f950, 0x1f95e],
[0x1f980, 0x1f991]
];
foreach($emojiUnicodeRange as $range)
    for($emojiUnicode=$range[0];$emojiUnicode<=$range[1];$emojiUnicode++)
        echo html_entity_decode('&#'.$emojiUnicode.';', 0, 'UTF-8');
```

The `html_entity_decode('&#'.$emojiUnicode.';', 0, 'UTF-8')` part converts the hex number to an entity and decode it as utf-8. Sadly there is no easier way to achieve this as far as I know.

Comment: Interesting but some of the Emojis within the range 1f300 to 1f5ff aren't recognized. Also why limit to UTF-8, if you don't mind me asking? Good answer, nonetheless.

Comment: @theflarenet most pages are utf-8. Never saw a page with a charset utf-16 or something like this. It converts the utf-16be representation of the emojis to UTF-8. If you want to use a different encoding feel free to use it :) || Are you sure that the emojis missing? Checked with a different browser? From my point of view there is no point why it should work with all emojis except a few in this range. The code is the same and the idea is the same. So I'm not sure where I could find the solution for the problem. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @theflarenet I'm sorry, but I cannot see an image when I follow the link. I don't know why. Can you share it with me on a different way?

Comment: @theflarenet seems like there are no emojis. The codes are reserved but no emoji is assigned to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is an updated answer base on kyle

```
$emojis = [];

$reg = "/^(?<start>[A-F0-9 ]+)(?:[\.]{2})?((?<end>[A-F0-9 ]+))?.*;/m";
$data = file_get_contents('https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/14.0/emoji-sequences.txt');

$matches = [];
preg_match_all($reg, $data, $matches);

$start = str_replace(' ', '', $matches['start']);
$end = str_replace(' ', '', $matches['end']);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($start); $i++) {
    $emojis[] = $start[$i];
    if (!empty($end[$i])) {
        for ($j = hexdec($start[$i]) + 0x1; $j <= hexdec($end[$i]); $j += 0x1) {
            $emojis[] = dechex($j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view a list of all the latest emojis from http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/6.0/emoji-data.txt but it seems like the main supported version is v5 which can be seen here http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/5.0/emoji-data.txt

You need to parse the results using regular expression to get the ranges, then you can iterate over the results of the preg_match and if there is an end number for the range you want to get all the values between the hex range.  You will likely want to cache these results if you're having to do this operation frequently.

```
$emojis = [];

$reg = "/^(?<start>[a-fA-F0-9]+)([\.]{2})?((?<end>[a-fA-F0-9]+))?\s+;/m";
$data = file_get_contents('http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/5.0/emoji-data.txt');

$matches = [];
preg_match_all($reg, $data, $matches);

$start = $matches['start'];
$end = $matches['end'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($start); $i++) {
    $emojis[] = $start[$i];
    if (!empty($end[$i])) {
        for ($j = $start[$i] + 0x1; $j <= $end[$i]; $j += 0x1) {
            $emojis[] = is_int($j) ? dechex($j) : $j;
        }
    }
}

// $emojis contains valid emojis from the file
```

You will want to test this, I just put it together real quick.